# Track progress when using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I am refactoring my program to use Parallel.ForEach. Before, when I was using a regular for loop, I was updating a WPF progress bar using Dispatcher, displaying the % completed by dividing the current array index by the array size. With a parallel foreach loop this does not display properly i.e. % jumps eratically, which is expected.

How can I update a WPF progress bar from a parallel for each loop so I can track the number of completed iterations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As SLaks suggests, you should just increment the progress bar value instead of setting it to the current index that you got from the `Parallel.For` method.

However, I would seriously consider using some less expensive way than sending a message to the UI thread with every iteration. If you have a large number of iterations, then sending a message with every iteration could be quite demanding. You could declare a local variable `count` and use `Interlocked.Increment` to increment the variable safely in the body of the parallelized loop.

- Then you could use something like `if (count % 10 == 0) // ...` to update the GUI only after 10 iterations. (This is not fully correct, as other threads may update the `count` before you check, but if it is just for the purpose of GUI notificiation, then it shouldn't matter - you definitely don't want to use `lock` in the loop body).
- Alternatively, you could create a Timer that would repeatedly check the value of `count` from the GUI thread and update the progress bar. This is perhaps even easier and you can guarantee that the progress bar will be updated enough often, but not more.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you finish an operation, you should post a message to the UI thread (by calling [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx) that increments the progress bar by 1.